# A rest with a lyric syllable under it? Is this a typo?

Tags: notation, voice, lyrics, rests

I am confused by this passage where a rest has a lyric syllable under it:

[image: Two measures of music from Spem in Alium, soprano 1 part, measures 94 and 95]

I do not understand what the singer would do here. Is this likely a typo?

The source is a specific edition of Thomas Tallis's *Spem in alium*. See https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Spem_in_alium_(Thomas_Tallis). The edition with this odd rest is the Hugh Keyte 2020 edition, CPDL #64682. By comparison, another full score linked on that page from Philip Legge (CPDL #22556) has a half-note C in this spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case this is very likely a typo. Reasons for it:

1. It would make little sense with Tallis
2. There are other editions having a reasonable note there
3. It is questionable how much editorial structure is behind this edition. Most likely it is missing thing such as professional proof-reading, so it might have some errors.

The more unlikely reason would be that this note is missing from the original sources, in which case replacing it by a rest does not sound like the most reasonable thing to do.

Generally Lyrics on Rests are used for spoken or shouted Text, which again does not make a lot of sense with Tallis.

Comment: Yes, all the clues point towards a misprint!

Comment: Thank you for replying! I was hesitant to assume error because the creator of this edition seems to be a serious scholar and this edition was produced for the Thomas Tallis Society. See https://www.thomas-tallis-society.org.uk/tallis-virtual-voice/.

Comment: @giskard22 It being issued by the Tallis society is little reason to assume there are no mistakes. The one who did the engraving is not the editor, but a single person either involved of contracted by the society. Not each academic research society has a big editorial structure with proof-readers and such. Thus it is to be expected to find more engraving mistakes than in an edition issued by a proper publisher.

Comment: IME, spoken/shouted/unpitched words are usually notated with a cross-head note, not a rest. I've never seen a notation such as in this question; I'd interpret it as a typo even without the corroborative evidence in this answer.

Comment: @gidds That is something you only really get with rhythmicized speech. If you study opera you’ll find many cases of spoken parts just notated under rests. But as I said, this does make little sense here.

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly a mistake.

The edition is said to be based primarily on Egerton MS 3512.  (The notes are [available in PDF format](https://www.thomas-tallis-society.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Spem-Preface-22-March-for-Website-2.pdf).)  The manuscript is [available online](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=egerton_ms_3512_f001r#), where you can plainly see that there should be a C in this position.  No mention of this variation is made in the notes.

(This manuscript has an English text, but it is the oldest surviving source for the music.)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this response will be of use to anyone intending to perform Spem in alium.

Of course the first note in Part 1 of bar 95 should be a minim C, not a minim rest.  It has long since been corrected, and I'm puzzled why this obvious boob has elicited such a prolix response.    I don't know what version of my edition the questioner used - perhaps the one made for the Taverner Choir and formerly available from The Early Music Company.

There are in fact two distinct versions of my edition, both now made obtainable gratis off-line by Thomas Tallis Society Editions.   The first is a revision of the one I initially made for the Taverners' double-LP recording of the complete church [sic] music of Thomas Tallis (1980s?), and is as close as we can probably hope to get to what will have been heard at the Creation Banquet of Prince Henry in 1610.  (Contrary to what is still universally claimed, the original Latin-texted manuscript discovered in the library of Nonsuch Palace the previous year will undoubtedly have been the basis of what was sung on that occasion.  The MS was subsequently destroyed or lost.)

The other version represents what I believe will have been heard at the first performance, no doubt under Tallis's direction, in c1571.  This has some differences of textual underlay, which can only with the greatest difficulty be (hopefully) deduced from the earliest surviving source, the British Library's hastily-made and error-strewn 'Egerton' MS of 1616 (sic), with its substituted English text.  It also has far less editorial ficta (sharpened 'leading notes'), in line with what is believed to have been English early-to-latish-16th-century practice in sacred music.  This latter version will be sung by The Sixteen in their RAH Prom on the 24th August.

It is worth pointing out that the Tudor Church Music edition, published in a commercial edition by Oxford University Press and eventually given a very hasty revision by the young Philip Brett, is based not on the Egerton MS but on the version in another BL MS, a cavalier and distressingly unsystematic attempt at restoring the Latin text by some unknown 18th-century musical antiquarian. It sounds well enough in performance, but is a musicological disaster.  So far as I am aware, my edition is the only one based entirely on the Egerton MS: all others known to me seem to derive - or have been copied - from the TCM/OUP rev Brett edition.  Phenomenal quantities of fantasy and sheer nonsense about Spem are still bandied about in supposedly reliable sources,  and performers and writers of programme notes should be cautious about reproducing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! As of this writing, the edition with this error is still available from the Thomas Tallis Society's website, on the `Virtual Voice – Resources` page at https://www.thomas-tallis-society.org.uk/tallisvirtualvoice-resources/. Both the `Choir Book 1` and `Full Score` files have the error. I think these files have a few others errors, though the ones I found are mostly basic typos in lyrics (e.g. "mi" instead of "mni"). A kind person at the Society said there is a newer file, but the website hadn't been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I've sung least one piece of (modern choral) music with a few syllables written under rests; it turned out that they were intended to be spoken.

However, that's clearly bad notation (and highly confusing!); an `×` notehead [seems to be the standard](/questions/6056/percussion-notes-in-the-vocals), and far more logical.